# 'Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to create a sql user which has the sole role of performing the login procedure but I keep getting the same error: `Access denied for user 'login'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I created the user like this:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT EXECUTE ON procedure `table`.`login` TO 'user'@'%';
```

If I try to login via terminal or mysql workbench or use the `mysql_real_connect()` function in my C client, i always get the same error.

Comment: Make sure you run also `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`;  after this.

Comment: I am creating the database from a mysql-workbench (.mwb) model using the "forward engineer" function. But I also tried to manually create the user using FLUSH PRIVILEGES; too. 
I keep getting the error.

Comment: I assumed that you change the function name and the user name, but just in case you did not: You are creating the user 'user', but the access denied is for the user 'login', Do you mixed the username and the procedure name? Also based on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97719/how-to-grant-execute-on-mysql is your database name `table`?  At that place should be the db name.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinstalling mariadb and using the following commands:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql -R
systemctl enable mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

My system is arch linux, this can also be useful to better manage the installation of mysql or mariadb: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL